# I got an error while executing mysqli_connect query

Tags: php, mysql

I got following error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server
>   on 'x.x.x.x' (111) in
>   /srv/disk1/2141710/www/vetalpallavi21.eu.pn/connection.php on line 7
>   Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '83.125.22.219'
>   (111)

I am hosting a site using free web hosting servers I don't know the IP address of that host server.So what should I give the first parameter in `mysqli_connect()` query and how can I get the IP address of that host.

Comment: show your full code and replacing actual credentials with fake ones. I.e.: `xxx`.

Comment: no response, ok I'm out. you have answers below, ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that information is included in the registration email. They send username and password along with php my admin login.

If that is the IP of the website you signed up at it's most likely not their SQL server(s).

PS: I am not sure if it's against stackoverflow TOS but it would be best if you don't show IPs for security and privacy :)

Comment: Oh yeah, Information is included in registered mail.

Answer (score 2):

If the server has mysql configured correctly you can use "localhost" instead of the IP address.

```
// use 172.0.0.1 OR "localhost"
$connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "dbname");
// localhost:
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
```

the login details(username/password) are often emailed to you.

Comment: `Warning: mysqli_connect()` OP is using the MySQLi_ API, not MySQL_. Two different animals here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ah sorry didn't see. Thanks for the heads up. Localhost should work though ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Let's see what the OP has to say ;-) question's a tad unclear though.